# Is it possible to make a Windows 7 (64bit) system’s drivers/software believe there is less RAM on the computer than there actually is?

Tags: windows, memory

Is it possible to make a Windows 7 (64bit) system’s drivers/software believe that there is *less* RAM on the computer than there actually is?

The reason I want to do this is older [E-mu systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-mu_Systems#Non-creative_sound_cards) sound card drivers have an annoying bug which only happens when having over 3GB of RAM on a 64bit Windows. E-mu systems won't fix this and the affected cards are very old models. And of course I don't want to remove RAM from my computer. This is why I would like to make the driver and software of this card see only 2GB of RAM instead of the 5GB my computer has.

Comment: One immediate and guaranteed fix is to use a virtual machine; you can specify exactly how much RAM the VM has, but a significant disadvantage is the loss in processing power (it will not have full access to the CPU).

If you wanted to guarantee that the driver is the problem, you could replicate your set-up in Virtualbox but with less RAM and test it that way.

Comment: You're asking an XY question.

Comment: @QuickishFM: Thanks for the virtual machine idea. There are big drawbacks, but in last resort it will help. It is already garanteed, it worked on this computer before I added RAM, then searching about the issue I learned that all those who still use these old cards faced this same bug when upgrading RAM over 3GB.

Comment: @sawdust: Sure, but they won't fix the bug and I can't fix it myself, so since it works well with 3GB and less, all I can do is giving it what it wants : less RAM.

Comment: What’s exact model of E-mu card you are attempting to deal with in a situation like this?

Comment: @QuickishFM And how do you plan on installing a physical sound card into a virtual machine?

Comment: @duskwuff I believe you can forward devices from your host to the guest, although I'm not sure how this performs with PCI devices (I know USB works well) and is most likely contingent on guest tools being installed (which isn't a problem in itself usually but adds a step to the setup)

Answer (score 1):

Only someone who knows reverse engineering could make what you ask happen. It would be an extremely hard task as you must work with x86 assembly code. Drivers and Software read the available RAM through system calls (WMI on Windows).

Hard coding these instructions will probably give you what you want. Of course, other issues might happen after these changes (e.g. the new driver and software will not have a valid signed certificate).

Comment: Thanks for these informations. I have too little knowledge in debugging and hack assembly to do this.  I wish it existed some sort of sandbox to run the driver and software into, that would fake the value returned by these calls, kind of like these tools which run trial softwares with a fake date to cheat the trial period.

Comment: Even if you did what I said, the issue is probably memory management related. Even if the driver read through WMI that it has only 2GBs of RAM, the OS itself has the responsibility to manage the memory through all the processes(including the driver). So, in reality even if you tricked the driver, you wouldn't trick the OS into not using the rest of the memory. My guess is that the driver is incompatible with Windows 7 in general.